# Number of atoms in cubic arrangement in a box

Tags: geometry

I want to figure out the spacing between neighbouring atoms in a cubic meter of a large amount if $10^{17}$ atoms were placed in perfect cubic structures within the cubic meter.

I’m not sure how to go about this. I can only manage to think that you will need $8$ atoms for the very first cube, and to add $4$ more to create the neighbouring cube in each dimension. Then fill this so that the total in all directs is equal to $10^{17}$?

Answer (score 2):

You can get an approximate answer by figuring out how large the side of a little cube should be in order to stack $10^{17}$ of them in your cubic meter. That number will be (about) the distance between your atoms.

Answer (score 1):

$27$ atoms would be arranged as $3\times 3\times 3$ so assuming atoms are positioned at the very edge of the cube the spacing would be $\frac{1}{3-1} = \frac{1}{2}$ m

So $10^{17}$ atoms would be arranged as $10^{\frac{17}{3}}\times 10^{\frac{17}{3}}\times 10^{\frac{17}{3}}$

The spacing would therefore be $\frac{1}{10^{\frac{17}{3}}-1}= 2.154439332\times 10^{-6}$ m